# CSOM get items from subsite

Tags: client-object-model

I want to be able to retrieve items from a subsite. I've found some code which works but only on the current site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MainFunction, "sp.js"); 

var objContext = null; 
var objWeb = null     
var objList = null;
var objItem = null;

    function MainFunction() {   
        objContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        objWeb = objContext.get_web();   
        objList = objWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("testList");

        objContext.load(objList);

        objContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));   
    }   

    function onSuccess(sender, args) {
        alert('Item Count: ' + objList.get_itemCount());
    }   

    function onFail(sender, args) {   
        alert('Some error has occured.');   
    }  
 </script>
```

How can I modify this to work on sub sites?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the URL to `new SP.ClientContext(url)`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245896(v=office.15).aspx):

```
var url = 'replace with server-relative or absolute URL';
var clientContext;
var website;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the client context for the specified URL.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    website = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert('URL of the website: ' + website.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```